Electron-forge with Angular
When I run npm run package, the process stops at "copying files" as shown in the screenshot below.

Angular & Node Version Details:
Angular CLI: 14.2.13
Node: 20.12.2 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 15.2.10

I followed the instructions on electron website and ran following two commands to install electron-forge:
npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli
npx electron-forge import

There was no issue in output of the above two.
The documentation says to ensure description isn't empty so I have added description in the package.json
{
  "name": "hakkim",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hakkim International",
  "main": "main.js",

What am I doing wrong?

Tip: when posting console output, please use a text block here. Images of text are harder to work with - just use text. Thanks!
